# Error in ld.exe | -lwinmm.lib not found

Tags: c++, audio, linker-errors

#### Hello world!

I am making a simple text based game in CodeBlocks, using C++. Because it would be really boring to play a text adventure with no music, I tried to add a command which is looping music. To be exact, this one:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("melody.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

I made sure the  melody.wav was  in the project's folder, but when I hit play I get the following error:

```
 ||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 ld.exe||cannot find -lwinmm.lib|
 ld.exe||cannot find -lwinmm.lib|
 ld.exe||cannot find -lwinmm.lib|
 ld.exe||cannot find -lwinmm.lib|
 ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
 ||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s)) ===|
```

I tried at first to make a linker flag in the build settings, as I thought this was the problem. The same again! I searched everywhere on Google, but got no proper answer! Please help me! Here is my code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    PlaySound(TEXT("melody.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);// - the correct code

    int test = 0;
    cin>>test;
    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if you could answer on how to get rid of that 
`ld.exe | cannot find -lwinmm.lib` ! :)

Comment: It is a typical MinGW hazard.  You should probably try libwinmm.a next.  Always best to *know* what the library names are of course, have a look see with Explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant THANK YOU!! IT WORKED!!

Answer (score 0):

remove the ".lib"

```
-lwinmm
```